# Issue with dependency files using Makefiles; file.d exist

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

I have the following sub-section of makefile that's used to generate the .d files

```
 -include $(wildcard $(patsubst %,$(OBJ_PATH)/%.d,$(basename $(SRCS))))
 
 
%.o: %.cpp
          @$(CC) -I$(INCLUDE_PATH) $(CFLAGS) $< -MM -MT $(@:.d=.o) > $(OBJ_PATH)/$(notdir $*.d)
          ${CC} -I$(INCLUDE_PATH) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $(OBJ_PATH)/$(notdir $@)
```

Sometimes when I build the project, I get the following error `/bin/sh: /path/to/my/build/dir/file.d: File exists`, although .d files does not exist.

Then I keep getting this error, the only way to get rid of it is to remove the whole enclosing directory and use git restore and the system will build successfully.

---

System info:

- git version 2.27.0
- GNU Make 4.2.1
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.5 (Ootpa)
- Free inodes: 426798634

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `@` from your line that creates the `.d` file, so you can see what the command line actually is.  It's always a bad idea to add `@` before your makefile is working 100% correctly.  Then you could cut and paste a full failure example into your question, including the command that generated the error message.

Your build lines are not right.  During the compilation, you need to use `$@` not `$(OBJ_PATH)/$(notdir $@)`.  It's always wrong to build a file that is not exactly `$@`.

During the creation of the dependency file `$(@:.d=.o)` is useless because `$@` is already set to `xxx.o` so changing the `.d` suffix to `.o` doesn't do anything.  You should just use `-MT $@` here.

You can replace `$(OBJ_PATH)/$(notdir $*.d)` with the simpler `%*.d`.

This error is being shown by the shell and there's really no way we can understand what the problem is with the info given.  Why would the shell give a "File exists" error when you use ">" to overwrite it?

I have a suspicion that it's not actually this command that is generating that error.